# Is there a way to create a split plane horizontally using the Apache POI library in Java? [EXCEL + APACHE POI]

Tags: java, apache-poi, apache-poi-4

using the createSplitPlane() method in XSSFSheet it is only able to do a 4 pane split. Is there a way to do a 2 plane split instead horizontally?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `Sheet.createSplitPane` one sets following parameters:

- xSplitPos - Horizontal position of split (in 1/20th of a point).
- ySplitPos - Vertical position of split (in 1/20th of a point).
- leftmostColumn - Left column visible in right pane.
- topRow - Top row visible in bottom pane
- activePane - Active pane. One of: PANE_LOWER_RIGHT, PANE_UPPER_RIGHT,
  PANE_LOWER_LEFT, PANE_UPPER_LEFT.

So if you set `xSplitPos` to `0` and `leftmostColumn` to `0`, then you should get what you want.

But there is a bug with `activePane`.

The constant fields in `Sheet` are as follows:

```
PANE_LOWER_RIGHT  0
PANE_UPPER_RIGHT  1
PANE_LOWER_LEFT   2
PANE_UPPER_LEFT   3
```

But the corresponding values in `org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.STPane` are:

```
INT_BOTTOM_RIGHT 1
INT_TOP_RIGHT    2
INT_BOTTOM_LEFT  3
INT_TOP_LEFT     4
```

So the first are 0-based while the second are 1-based.

That's why one needs using `+1` to each of the `Sheet` constants.

Example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

class CreateExcelSplitPane {
    
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  try (
       Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("Excel.xlsx") ) {
       //Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(); FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("Excel.xls") ) {

   Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
   
   sheet.createSplitPane(0, 100*20, 0, 9, Sheet.PANE_UPPER_LEFT+1);
   
   workbook.write(fileout);
  }
 }
}
```

Result:

[image]

And when using

```
...
sheet.createSplitPane(100*20, 0, 3, 0, Sheet.PANE_UPPER_LEFT+1);
...
```

the result looks like:

[image]

This is tested and works using `apache poi 4.1.1` as well as `apache poi 5.2.2`.

There are additional issues in `HSSF` using `HSSFSheet.createSplitPane`. But that's another question.

Comment: I created https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66173 for the Sheet constants issue.